# How do I see what order the messages go in between two different windows?

Tags: winapi, spy++

I have two windows with a child/parent relationship.  I need to see the messages that each gets in the order that they occur to each *relative* to each other.

Is there a way to do that with Spy++ or other software?

Comment: Not with Spy++.  I doubt you'll have much luck when you go shopping.

Comment: If the messages are posted then Spy++ can display the origin time of the message via the Options tab on the Messages dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when you have a `Messages` window up, you can go to `Messages->Logging Options` and then select under `Windows` tab, `Additional Windows` group, other windows that may be useful.